# How to access GCE Mesos Spark UI

Tags: apache-spark, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, mesosphere

Running Spark 1.4.1 on a Mesos cluster using GCE.  I can get Spark up and running, but cannot access the UI for either Mesos or Spark.

I have tried:

- MesosMasterExternalIP:4040
- MesosMasterExternalIP:5050
- MesosMasterExternalIP:7070
- MesosMasterExternalIP:7077

I also tried stopping Spark, ran
     "ps ax | grep spark-shell" 
and killed all processes, restarted Spark.  No success.

I was trying to follow the instructions in [Paco Nathan's post](http://ceteri.blogspot.com/2014/09/spark-atop-mesos-on-google-cloud.html) Section 5, but keep getting a "This webpage is not available" error when ever I try to get to the UI via my laptop browser. (Chrome on ubuntu 14.04)

Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: Even if you've configured the firewall in GCE, did you also make sure that the local one on your instance isn't blocking incoming traffic? For example, with Ubuntu /etc/init.d/iptables save && /etc/init.d/iptables stop

Comment: hey @thom-rogers any updates on this?

Comment: Michael,  I checked and confirmed that ports 4040 and 5050 were both available on my laptop which is the local machine trying to comunicate with the cluster,  However, no change in access.

Comment: Michael,  I checked and confirmed that ports 4040 and 5050 were both available on my laptop which is the local machine trying to communicate with the cluster,  However, no change in access.  I did find an env var that I forgot to export (export MESOS_MASTER=xx.xxx.xxx.xxx) and after exporting that, I could access the Mesos console at 5050.  Still couldn't access Spark at 4040 though.

Comment: Oddly the IP of the address for MESOS_MASTER is the *internal* IP address of the master.  Yet the browser communicates thru the external IP.  So I don't know why the address of the internal master ID would matter(even tho its the same machine)

Comment: I meant the local firewall on the GCE instance.